# Given $|f(x,y)|\le \sin^2(x^2+y^2)$. Is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Knowing that $|f(x,y)|\le \sin^2(x^2+y^2)$ in all $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$.

I don't know how to approach this question, I have learnt recently the definition of differentiability for two variable functions, which is (for point $(0,0)$): 
$f(0+\Delta x,0+ \Delta y)-f(0,0)=f_x(0,0)\Delta x+f_y(0,0)\Delta y+\epsilon\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$, and if $\epsilon \to 0$ when $\Delta x,\Delta y \to0$ then we say $f$ is differentiable. 
will the definition of differentiability help me here? I'm finding it extremely hard to find counter examples and check them, so if theres any trick I would love to hear. 
I would appreciate any hints and pushes in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the partial derivatives are the zero functions, as we see that
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\right|&=\dfrac{|f(h,k)|}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{\sin^{2}(h^{2}+k^{2})}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\\
&=\sin(h^{2}+k^{2})\cdot\dfrac{\sin(h^{2}+k^{2})}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\dfrac{h^{2}+k^{2}}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\\
&=\sin(h^{2}+k^{2})\cdot\dfrac{\sin(h^{2}+k^{2})}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\cdot\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sin(h^{2}+k^{2})}{h^{2}+k^{2}}\rightarrow 1,~~~~(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0),
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\right|\rightarrow 0,~~~~(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood how you proved that $\epsilon \to 0$, but I don't get why the partial derivatives are the zero functions, how did you reach that?

Comment: You need to guess actually.

Comment: The linear function is $T(h,k)=[\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y][h,k]^{T}$ and you are to show that $|f(h,k)-f(0,0)-T(h,k)|/\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you mean, I assumed that $h,k$ in your answer are $\Delta x, \Delta y$ in the definition I wrote, and you said you can guess that the partial derivatives are zeroes, but that makes the proof work for functions that have partial derivatives zero? I'm sorry I've learnt this material this week and I can't understand it :(

Comment: If you are manage to show that $f(0+\Delta x,0+\Delta y)-f(0,0)=\varphi_{1}(0,0)\Delta x+\varphi_{2}(0,0)\Delta y+\epsilon\sqrt{(\Delta x)^{2}+(\Delta y)^{2}}$ with the required convergence, then the partial derivatives exist and they are simply $\varphi_{1}(0,0)=\partial f/\partial x(0,0)$...

Comment: Thanks!! so basically if the definition works with the assumed partial derivatives values, it proves that these are the values of the partial derivatives in the specific point we assumed?

Comment: Yes, that is the trick. But this trick is not hard to prove mathematically.

Comment: why not just use $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ ?

Comment: Oh, just missed that, sorry.

Comment: @user284331 Thinking about it again, couldn't I just say $0 \le |f(0,0)| \le |sin(0)| = 0$. and then $0 \le |f(h,0)| \le |sin(h^2)| = 0$, so $f(h,0)=0$ for any $h$ that goes to zero. and same for $f(0,h)=0$. and then I can prove that the partial derivatives are zeroes by definition, would this be a legit proof?

Comment: That is one way of proving it.